# Does not contain definition for this

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and its been really difficult for me. I'm writing this program in C# and this is error that I'm facing.

> Error 1   'Lab1.Invoice' does not contain a definition for 'partNumber' and no extension method 'partNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'Lab1.Invoice' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code:

```
    using System;


    namespace Lab1
    {
        class InvoiceTest
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string partNumber, partDescription;
                int quantity;
                decimal Iprice;

                Console.WriteLine("Part Number:");
                partNumber = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Part Description:");
                partDescription = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Quantity:");
                quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Price:");
                Iprice = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());



                Invoice invoice = new Invoice(partNumber, partDescription, quantity, Iprice);

                Console.WriteLine("Order: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Part Number: {0}", invoice.partNumber);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", invoice.pDescription);
                Console.WriteLine("Quantity: {0}", invoice.Quantity);
                Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", invoice.Price);
                Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", invoice.GetInvoiceAmount());

            }
        }
    }

Here is the code for Invoice:<br>
namespace Lab1
{
    class Invoice
    {
        private int qty;
        private decimal price;
        private string pNumber { get; set; }
        private string pDescription { get; set; }

        public Invoice(string partNumber, string partDescription, int quantity, decimal Iprice)
        {
            pNumber = partNumber;
            pDescription = partDescription;
            Quantity = quantity; 
            Price = Iprice;
        }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get 
            { 
                return qty; 
            }

            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    qty = value;
                else
                    qty = 1;
            }
        }

        public decimal Price
        {
            get
            {
                return price;

            }

            set
            {
                if (value > 0)

                    price = value;

                else
                    price = 1;
            }

        }

        public decimal GetInvoiceAmount()


        {
            return Quantity * Price;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The error is very descriptive. Where is the definition of `Invoice`

Comment: Do you have a property called partNumber in the definition of your `Invoice` class?

Comment: Its a public class created within another class

Comment: @hades post the definition of `Invoice`

Comment: no it isnt a property

Comment: Is it a field then @hades? Is it private? Please post the code for `Invoice`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We shouldn't be trying to guess what the `Invoice` class looks like. (Note that you can reduce your example significantly. There's no need for five different properties/fields/whatever just to show one error.)

Comment: Ive edited my question the invoice code is below

Comment: Okay, so the compiler is (unsurprisingly) correct - you don't have an accessible field or property called `partNumber`. There's a parameter to the constructor called `partNumber`, but how do you expect that to be accessed later?

Comment: Note how you've got properties that *are* okay - `Price` and `Quantity`. You've got a *private* property called `pNumber`. Is that meant to be `PartNumber` and public by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Add a public property called `PartNumber` and a public property called `PartDescription` in your `Invoice` class.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

`Invoice` doesn't contain a property named `partNumber`.

You send it through the constructor, but assign it to a property named: `pNumber`

Use it or rename it to `PartNumber`

Edit:
Just noticed it's a private property - change it to `public` as well (you can leave the setter `private`)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add up on the comments you already got, If you want to have a private setter, then create a property with private setter.

```
class Invoice
{
    private int qty;
    private decimal price;
    public string partNumber { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the:

```
private string pNumber to a public string pNumber
```

in order for it to be accessed. I did the same thing for `pDescription`